# Why am i getting an error on @Valid in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

When I add `@Valid` to create a form in Spring MVC, I get an red line under the `@Valid`.

Please advice.

Comment: What does that error say? Have you imported `@Valid` in you class?

Comment: What have you found with Google? Have you tried that? What isn't working exactly? Do you have any errors? What have you tried to fix it? Please read and follow the instructions on this page to produce a high-quality question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It doesnt show me if i have to import or not. It asks me to create an annotation 'Valid'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't include `.jar` file with compiled classes to your classpath.

More information about using Spring validation you may find [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/).

Comment: How do i add the .jar file?